# revved filename references is database

Tags: caching, yeoman

I am currently using yeoman in my project to perform building and scaffolding etc. When you build with yeoman it uses usemin to prefix filenames with hashs to help with cacheing. I like this functionality, as sometimes we change images slightly and want them to update without waiting for the cache to clear.

The problem I am having, is that some of these image files are referenced from our database as well. For example for product X we have productx.jpg in the image field of our database. When getting this from the database there is obviously a problem because productx.jpg is now called 30341d.productx.jpg.

Is there a way to get around this? Possibly something to do with the .htaccess file? Would 
I have to write new rewrite conditions every time I build the project? This could get annoying with even 20-30 and a build every week or two.

Answer (score 1):

you can edit your gruntfile find this:

`rev: {
      js: 'scripts/**/*.js',
      css: 'styles/**/*.css',
      img: 'images/**'
    },`

and change to

`img: ''`

to prevend yeoman from adding version prefixes to your image files inside the image folder.

But you should also strictly separate between image data that belongs to the layout part of your project and data that belongs to the content data part. All layout critical images should reside inside the images/ folder and may only be referenced from css or in some cases from html templates (but not from the database). Your content data files in a separate folder (or database or cdn) that way these files don't get any version numbers.